# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n} $

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n} $
I know that result $\frac{331}{910}$ because I checked it in Mathematica but I have troubles with calculate that.
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n} = ... = $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^n \cdot (\frac{2}{11})^n+2\cdot(\frac{2}{11})^n\cdot(-1)^n + \frac{1}{11^n})$$ But what should be done after...?

Comment: Now you have $3$ geometric series, all convergent, and you can use the fact that for $|p|<1$, $$\sum_{p=0}^\infty p^n=\frac{1}{1-p}$$

Comment: Best answer! Repeat that as normal answer and I will mark that as the best :) @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|p|<1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n=\frac{p}{1-p}$, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{11^n}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{11^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{11^n}\\
= \frac{\frac{4}{11}}{1-\frac{4}{11}}-2\frac{\frac{2}{11}}{1+\frac{2}{11}}+\frac{\frac{1}{11}}{1-\frac{1}{11}}\\=\frac{4}{7}-\frac{4}{13}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{331}{910}$$

Answer (score 1):

Once you've expanded $(2^n-(-1)^n)^2=4^n-2(-2)^n+1$, split up the summation as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{11^n}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{11^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{11^n}.$$

These are just geometric series, so you can apply the formula

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}.$$